# Possible mistake in proof of limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

Please if someone with enough reputation could show my image it would be great.

[image]

In this limit question, at the point where it states:

Take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ I really don't follow the logic at all. Since $a \in (0,1)$ then as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $|f(x)-f(a^nx)| \rightarrow |f(x)-f(0)|$, did they confuse $f(0)$ with $0$? Because otherwise how do you go from $$|f(x)-f(0)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{1-a} |x|$$ to $$|f(x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{1-a} |x|$$

It is also very strange that the first property was not used.

Comment: Perhaps the first property was meant to read $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$? That would take care of both of your issues, wouldn't it?

Comment: Actually, that still leaves another issue: their interpretation of the second statement is equivalent to $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(ax)}{x}=0.$$ I suspect that something has gone seriously wrong, here. It seems that each instance of "$x\to\infty$" should actually be "$x\to 0$," unless I'm missing a great deal.

Comment: It's also worth noting that they never claimed that the function was continuous, so you can't simply replace $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|f(x)-f\bigl(a^nx\bigr)\right|$ with $\bigl|f(x)-f(0)\bigr|$ without proof.

Comment: I think that @CameronBuie has written altogether a pretty good answer to your question.

Comment: I can make it an answer, if you like.

Comment: The first statement alone already implies the desired conclusion (limit of product is product of limits), which again indicates something is wrong here.

Comment: This is only if the limits are defined right. But $\lim_{x\to \infty} x = \infty$

Comment: The relevant product, here (if the limits are defined right) is $f(x)\cdot\frac1x.$ The limit of each as $x\to\infty$ is $0,$ so the limit of their product is $0,$ too. Thus, as @Shalop points out, the first statement is enough, by itself. As Salamam points out in the answer below, the second statement is enough, by itself. This redundancy, together with the mismatching interpretation of the second statement, makes me all but certain at this point that the limits should all be $x\to 0,$ instead.

Comment: Yeah mate cheers my bad. Seems you might have a good point that the question could be as $x \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have, for $x$ enough great,

$$|f (x)|=|f (x)-f (0)+f (0)|\le $$
$$|f (x)-f (0)|+|f (0)|\le$$

$$ \frac {\epsilon}{1-a}|x|+|f (0)|$$

thus

$$\frac{|f (x)|}{|x|}\le \frac {\epsilon}{1-a}+\frac {|f (0)|}{|x|} $$

and use the fact that
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac {|f (0)|}{|x|}=0$$

You don't need the first hypothesis.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question. The OP asks to either explain the given proof, or to verify the issues that the OP has pointed out with the proof. (For what it's worth, I didn't downvote.)

Comment: @CameronBuie He said why they took $f (0)=0$

Comment: Yes, that is *one* of the issues that the OP pointed out.

Comment: @CameronBuie So why this downvote.

Comment: I don't know. I'm merely speculating why someone may have downvoted.

Comment: This seems correct. Thanks.